# Bitlocker on Windows 11 local account

Tags: windows, bitlocker, microsoft, windows-11

I've recently upgraded my computer security by encrypting all the drives on in with BitLocker (I'm using Windows 11 Pro).
Unfortunately, I ran into a rather fastidious bug that prevents me from converting the local user I was using to a Microsoft one. After spending a couple of evenings trying to get a solution to the bug (some other people reported the same exact issue, but no solution is around), I'm stuck with two accounts on the pc. Both admin, one Microsoft, one local.
The pc boots regularly and the pass/PIN is required to unlock the Windows screen lock: the Microsoft account can be accessed only with a PIN while the local one can accessed with both a PIN and a password.
First of all, my understanding is that the PIN is necessary for the TPM authentication and if not introduced correctly will block the computer and ask the full 40something character long pass string.
But that can be clearly be circumvented with the password as the local account cannot be set up to be PIN only?

My question is, do I really need to fix that account issue and keep only the Microsoft account on the pc to be reasonably safe, or not? For how much strange it might be (or it seems to me), I cannot find on the internet a single article that compares clearly the security of a local account with passwords with a Microsoft one with a PIN only login.

On top of all that, around the web some people also suggest that a BitLocker pre-boot PIN should be turned on. It's that something that is expected to have a reasonable amount of security today or the regular setting (encrypting drives and letting windows boot as before) is ok for most people?